# Spark read key value pairs from the file into a Dataframe

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to read a log file and convert it into a spark dataframe.

**Input File Content:**

```
dateCreated   : 20200720
customerId    :  001
dateCreated   : 20200720
customerId    :  002
dateCreated   : 20200721
customerId    :  003
```

**Expected Dataframe:**

```
---------------------------
|dateCreated | customerId |
---------------------------
|20200720    | 001        |
|20200720    | 002        |
|20200721    | 003        |
|------------|------------|
```

**Spark code :**

```
val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate
    val inputFile = "C:\\log_data.txt"
    val rddFromFile = spark.sparkContext.textFile(inputFile)

    val rdd = rddFromFile.map(f => {
      f.split(":")
    })

    rdd.foreach(f => {
      println(f(0) + "\t" + f(1))
    })
```

Any idea on how to convert the above rdd to a required DF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> "cat /tmp/sample/input.csv".!
dateCreated   : 20200720
customerId    :  001
dateCreated   : 20200720
customerId    :  002
dateCreated   : 20200721
customerId    :  003
```

```
scala> val df = spark.read.text("/tmp/sample").select(split($"value",":").as("data"))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [data: array<string>]
```

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---------------------------+
|data                       |
+---------------------------+
|[dateCreated   ,  20200720]|
|[customerId    ,   001]    |
|[dateCreated   ,  20200720]|
|[customerId    ,   002]    |
|[dateCreated   ,  20200721]|
|[customerId    ,   003]    |
+---------------------------+
```

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

scala> val windowSpec = Window.orderBy($"id".asc)

scala> df
.select(trim($"data"(0)).as("data"),trim($"data"(1)).as("values"))
.select(map($"data",$"values").as("data"))
.select($"data"("dateCreated").as("dateCreated"),$"data"("customerId").as("customerId"))
.withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id)
.withColumn("customerId",lead($"customerId",1).over(windowSpec))
.where($"customerId".isNotNull)
.drop("id")
.show(false)

+-----------+----------+
|dateCreated|customerId|
+-----------+----------+
|20200720   |001       |
|20200720   |002       |
|20200721   |003       |
+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Is there any other way, apart from using windowing functions? . I hope windowing functions are costly operations and the input file is large in size.